I'm using serverless framework with AWS, What kind of policies I should to grant?
I'm using serverless to create some lambdas in AWS. I'm trying to follow the best practices of AWS IAM, grant exactly the permission to a user.
The problem is, I didn't find some information about what kind of policies serverless is using to upload the code written to AWS Lambda. I granted
LambdaFullAccess
S3FullAccess

I don't feel comfortable granting full access, but I'm not pretty sure exactly what policies I should to grant.
For example, right now I found a new serverless upload restriction
User is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:DescribeStackResource

Now I should to add this rule to the user, but this is weird I don't want to test every time what new policy is requiered.
Does a list of policies required exists?

As far as I am aware of, there is no place to find a grant list of permissions required to perform any specific AWS action. That being said, there are a few things that may be helpful for your situation:

It is recommended to have restricted access for operational purposes, but usually it does not make sense to apply strict rules for development. Unless there is a specific task role that performs and only performs Lambda code upload operation, I won't recommend spend too much time to figure out the exact boundary of a deployment role. Admin access is appropriate in this case.
For lambda code upload, the only required permission is UpdateFunctionCode. If you upload the file to S3, the S3 permission is also required. It seems you are also using CloudFormation to make deployments. It is a bit unclear how you are deploying the code, as the permissions required differ by the frameworks. Sometimes it is just a trial-and-error process.
IAM Policy Simulator let you test your role permissions, if you know which operations you are performing.

